# Had better plus present perfect vs 3rd conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

If I say

> You had better have invited him.

I'm referring to the point that the addressed person hasn't been invited yet. I was thinking that I can also say it like this:

> It would have been better if you had invited him.

and I think, there is not much difference between these two sentences. In both cases, the addressed person can still pick up the phone and invite him. Am I right?

Comment: You are wrong. To me, both sentences imply that the opportunity for issuing the invitation is past (the second is much more idiomatic  than the first). To recommend a future action, you should say "You had better invite him."

Comment: *You'd better have invited him* normally implies you probably *did* do it (speaker isn't certain of that, but he's saying there may be bad consequences for you if in fact you *didn't*). But it can be used in "Past in the Future" contexts, such as *You'd better have fixed it before I get home*, where obviously there can't be any such implication regarding whether you did or didn't. On the other hand, *It would have been better if you had invited him* can *only* refer to a "fixed" past situation, with the very strong implication that you *didn't* invite him.

Comment: Okay - there *are* conexts where the second form doesn't *have* to imply "can't be changed". *"I've arranged a team meeting for tomorrow, and I'd like you to attend". "I'm sorry, but I can't be there. **It would have been better** if you'd given me a bit more notice". "That's okay - tell me when you **are** free, and I'll reschedule the meeting".*